# Understanding reactivity work technically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I work with a simple store (see code). And it works very well. So I can change data in a RouterView and it will be changed immediately in a Navigation Component. It sounds like an observer pattern to me, doesn't it?

```js
// store.js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
    gender: "",
    name: "",
});
```

**Question:** But I would like to know how it works and how the same would look like in Vanilla JS.

Comment: I think you best read e.g. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html and then google something like `building reactive dom in javascript`

Comment: Thanks for the link. The answer below links exactly to what I actually already need. The same for your link, too. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue):

> In Vue 3, Proxies are used for reactive objects and getter / setters are used for refs.

The page also provides pseudo-code:

```js
function reactive(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, key) {
      track(target, key)
      return target[key]
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
      target[key] = value
      trigger(target, key)
    }
  })
}

function ref(value) {
  const refObject = {
    get value() {
      track(refObject, 'value')
      return value
    },
    set value(newValue) {
      value = newValue
      trigger(refObject, 'value')
    }
  }
  return refObject
}
```